# Using KeyFieldBasedPartitioner and Secondary Sorting in Java Hadoop similar to Hadoop Streaming

Tags: java, hadoop, partitioner

When using Hadoop streaming, the partitioner and sorter can be set and configurated like this:

```
hadoop jar /opt/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.1.jar \
-D mapreduce.map.output.key.field.separator=. \
-D stream.map.output.field.separator= \
-D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=2 \
-D num.key.fields.for.partition=2 \
-D mapreduce.job.output.key.comparator.class=org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.KeyFieldBasedComparator \
-partitioner org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner
```

I would like to the same thing in my Java `main()` method. The sorting can be achieved like this:

```
job.setSortComparatorClass(KeyFieldBasedComparator.class);    
KeyFieldBasedComparator.setKeyFieldComparatorOptions(job, "-k 1,2");
```

The method `.setKeyFieldPartitionerOptions` in the class `KeyFieldBasedPartitioner`, however, is not `static`:

```
KeyFieldBasedPartitioner partitioner = new KeyFieldBasedPartitioner();
partitioner.setKeyFieldPartitionerOptions(job, "-k 1,2");
```

In the job object, I can only set a class, however:

```
job.setPartitionerClass(KeyFieldBasedPartitioner.class);
```

How can the above options be set in this case? I could, of course, implement my own partitioner class, but why the effort if there should be a simple way?

Comment: Are you using Job class or JobConf?

Comment: I am using the Job class as far as I know. Newest Hadoop version.

Comment: check if this article is useful for you : http://blog.zaloni.com/secondary-sorting-in-hadoop

Comment: Unfortunately, the link uses custom implementation of the Comparable classes. That did the trick for me as well, but it was a lot more work than if I could have used the already implemented classes. I am therefore still interested in an answer. But thanks for the link anyway!